# Bootstrap 3 and Angular JS - row with table and div

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am newbie to front-end who is using bootstrap and can't really figure out how to achive this effect:

---

I talk about row with table and hidden div. Table is 100% width and when hidden div appears after button is clicked, table will resize to 60-70% and rest of width will be for div. When I close div(makem it hidden), then table will back to 100% width.

Could you help me please to understand how should I do it the most common and correct way?

Comment: Could you show your code, any efforts, attemps?

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Here! Without AngularJs. You could add some animation to make it more fluid.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        table{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background: grey;
            float: left;
        }
        table tr, td, th{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #divToResize{
            width: 0;
            height: 100px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background: blue;
            float: left;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        'use strict';
        let resized = false;
        function resize(){
            if (resized === false){
                document.getElementById("tableToResize").style.width = "60%";
                document.getElementById('divToResize').style.width = "40%";
                resized = true;
            } else{
                document.getElementById("tableToResize").style.width = "100%";
                document.getElementById('divToResize').style.width = "0";
                resized = false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <table cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%;" id="tableToResize">
            <tr>
                <th>Header 1</th>
                <th>Header 2</th>
                <th>Header 3</th>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Header 1</td>
                <td>Header 2</td>
                <td>Header 3</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Header 1</td>
                <td>Header 2</td>
                <td>Header 3</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Header 1</td>
                <td>Header 2</td>
                <td>Header 3</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="divToResize">
            I love Food
        </div>
        <button onclick="resize()">Resize</button></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Live Preview:  [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/waENZNjKZPvU1Kl20WP6?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Angular provides a number of built-in directives for manipulating CSS styling conditionally/dynamically - for ex. ng-class - use when the set of CSS styles is static/known ahead of time

Here is simple way to change width of table cell, after click :

```
<button ng-hide="click" ng-click="click = true">click</button>
<button ng-hide="!click" ng-click="click = false">click</button>
<table id="mytable">

      <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="data in data">
        <td >
           {{data.person}} 
        </td>
         <td style="background:grey" ng-class="{after_click_width: click}">
           {{data.person}} 
        </td>

    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

style:

```
.after_click_width {
  width: 70%
}
```

working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/DuxbZFZbUpjU2BSLlpm2?p=preview